# Convert jpg to bmp in an ARM Cortex M4 MCU

Tags: arm, images, programming

I'm currently working in a project that involves the use of an ARM cortex M4 MCU, specifically STM32F429, which has an embedded LCD controller which uses the bmp image format to show the images in the LC screen. The image is sent from a computer to the MCU and then is shown in the screen, nonetheless due to the transferring time of the bmp picture the current image format is becoming an issue (I'm using serial transmission since the MCU does not support an embedded OS), therefore I would like to know if is possible to send the image in "jpg" format and convert it to bmp directly in the MCU using a hal extension or another library which does not require an OS to process the image.

Comment: How big of an image (pixels/bpp)? How much memory does your MCU have available? Does your system support RLE BMPs? How long is "too long" to transfer?